# CSS custom property (variable) inheritance override & unset

Tags: css

Given the below DOM hierarchy, the same elements (sharing the same class) are nested, and so they share the same CSS variable `--show`.

When `--show` is set on the parent to any value (here it's set to `1`) I would like it to affect only that node and not any children, therefore I set `--show: unset;` so each element would start with that, unless instructed otherwise, and the inspector agrees:

But for some reason, `--show` is **not really using the `unset` value for the children**, like expected.

The inspector shows it's being overridden like expected, but in reality it is not, and still have the value of the parent, `1`:

[image]

```css
.foo{
  --show: unset;  
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: var(--show, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class='foo' style='--show:1'>
  <div class='foo'>1 - should have opacity 0</div>
  <div class='foo'>2 - should have opacity 0</div>
</div>
```

### Based on the principle that `unset` uses the fallback value:

```css
body{
  --show: unset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 999px red;
  opacity: var(--show, 0);
}
```

Comment: you are looking for initial not unset

Comment: Ha right yes, thanks @Temani!

Comment: Makes sense because `unset` value is basically canceling itself and thus the value fallbacks to whatever value was (if) defined up the tree.